# WCF Implications of Increasing MaxObjectsInGraph

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there any disadvantage in increasing this value other than not capturing when the server tries to return unusually large responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things I can think of are:

- Performance (More items to serialize)
- Memory Usage (Larger lists/arrays)
- Potentially more exploitable (Someone could spam you with very large requests and cause a DOS condition)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is performance. If your use case allows, you should consider returning only a "page" of data at a time. Again, you may not have that option...